# How to Solve Disjunction Elimination Proof

Tags: propositional-calculus

How would you prove the following by disjunction elimination?

Premises: 
A ∨ B , 
A ∨ C

Conclusion: 
A ∨ (B ∧ C)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Apply two "nested" *Disjunction elimination*s to the premises : three cases : 1) $A$; it's done. 2) $B$ : two sub-cases : 2.1) $A$ : done. 2.2) $C$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Premise: A v B
2. Case 1: A
3. Then, we can just get A v (B ∧ C) and it's works.
4. Case 2: B (where A is false)
5. Premise: A v C
6. since NOT A, we get C (because A v C is true)
7. so, A v (B ∧ C)